# Resize a div with a ratio in Javascript (without Jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, resize

I'm coding an editing tool in Javascript (I can't use Jquery and HTML Canvas for this project). So the goal is to use the mouse on the edge of a div (ex : a square) and resize the div proportionally (use a ratio). My code right now can resize the square but not proportionnaly. I'd like to make this "https://jqueryui.com/resizable/#aspect-ratio" in pure javascript.

My Code :

```js
var resizeHandle = document.getElementById('handle_bottom_right');
var box = document.getElementById('box');
resizeHandle.addEventListener('mousedown', initialiseResize, false);
var scale = 1.1


function initialiseResize(e) {
 window.addEventListener('mousemove', startResizing, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', stopResizing, false);
}

function startResizing(e) {
  box.style.width = (e.clientX - box.offsetLeft) + 'px';
  box.style.height = (e.clientY - box.offsetTop) + 'px';
}

function stopResizing(e) {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', startResizing, false);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopResizing, false);
}


function doubleClicked(element){
  setTimeout(function(){
    if(document.activeElement !== element){
        element.contentEditable = false;
    }
  }, 300);
}
```

```css
#box {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: white;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#handle_bottom_right {
    background-color: #727272;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    cursor: se-resize;
    position:absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onclick="showCoords(event);">
    <p onclick="this.contentEditable=true; doubleClicked(this);" onblur="this.contentEditable=false;" contenteditable="false">double click me to change me</p>
    <div id="handle_bottom_right"></div>
</div> 
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
```

Is there someone who has any idees how to solve this?

Comment: `box.style.height = box.style.width*ratio`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var resizeHandle = document.getElementById('handle_bottom_right');
var box = document.getElementById('box');
resizeHandle.addEventListener('mousedown', initialiseResize, false);
var scale = 1.1


function initialiseResize(e) {
 window.addEventListener('mousemove', startResizing, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', stopResizing, false);
}

function startResizing(e) {
  var w = (e.clientX - box.offsetLeft);
  box.style.width = w + 'px';
  //box.style.height = (e.clientY - box.offsetTop) + 'px';
  box.style.height = Math.round(scale*w)+'px';
}

function stopResizing(e) {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', startResizing, false);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopResizing, false);
}


function doubleClicked(element){
  setTimeout(function(){
    if(document.activeElement !== element){
        element.contentEditable = false;
    }
  }, 300);
}
```

```css
#box {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: white;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#handle_bottom_right {
    background-color: #727272;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    cursor: se-resize;
    position:absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onclick="showCoords(event);">
    <p onclick="this.contentEditable=true; doubleClicked(this);" onblur="this.contentEditable=false;" contenteditable="false">double click me to change me</p>
    <div id="handle_bottom_right"></div>
</div> 
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
```